# Read instance for Associative Computations Tree

Tags: haskell, tree, monads

I have type

```
data EvalATree b a = Leaf a | Node ([b] -> a) [EvalATree b a]
```

I have written Show and Foldable instances, 'Edited:' taking that a = b

```
instance (Show a, Show a) => Show (EvalATree a a) where
  show :: (Show a, Show a) => EvalATree a a -> String
  show (Leaf a) = "Leaf " ++ show a
  show (Node g trees) = "Node " ++ show (calcNode (Node g trees)) ++ " " ++ show trees

instance Foldable (EvalATree a) where
  foldr f z (Leaf x) = f x z
  foldr f z (Node func subtrees) = foldr (\subtree acc -> foldr f acc subtree) z subtrees
```

**Problem**

I can't realize how to write Read instance.
Functions for Node are just names, which means i have to take functions from dictionary, and i can't do this either.

example of tree string

```
let tree = Node someFunction [Leaf 1, Leaf 2, Leaf 3]
let treeStr = "Node someFunction [Leaf 1, Leaf 2, Leaf 3]"
```

I tried writing parsers.

```
parseEvalATree :: (Read a, Read a) =>  Parser a -> Parser (EvalATree a a)
parseEvalATree parserA = parseLeaf parserA <|> parseNode intFunctionDict parserA

parseLeaf :: (Read a, Read a) => Parser a -> Parser (EvalATree a a)
parseLeaf parserA = Leaf <$> parserA

parseNode :: (Read a, Read a) => Map String ([a] -> a) -> Parser a -> Parser (EvalATree a a)
parseNode dict parserA = do
  string "Node"
  spaces
  funcName <- many1 letter
  spaces
  subtrees <- between (char '[') (char ']') (parseEvalATree parserA `sepBy` char ',')
  let func = case Map.lookup funcName dict of
        Just f -> f
        Nothing -> error "Function not defined"
  return (Node func subtrees)
```

But i couldn't apply them.

Comment: This just isn't a type with good Show or Read instances. Why have you decided to write some?

Comment: @amalloy i know, but i have a task, which i should do. For Show instance: Node can be written as 'Node {Node function result} subtrees', so it's become much easier.

Comment: Looks suspicious that parseNode consumes the string "Node" but parseLeaf doesn't consume the string "Leaf".  Also I don't think the parser allows spaces after commas or square brackets, which it probably should.

Comment: Are you sure the task is "Implement Read and Show instances for this type"? Unless there are clarifying details to explain how to address all the obvious issues, it's just a bad task.

Comment: @DavidFletcher Yes, I tried to write parsers, I just don't understand how to parse value inside leaf, because there is dynamic type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only really need to identify "Leaf" or "Node something" and then
defer to the Read instance of the element type for the rest.

Something like this might be good enough.

```
instance Read a => Read (EvalATree a a) where
  readsPrec _ s =
    case lex s of
      [("Leaf", s')] -> [(Leaf x, s'') | (x, s'') <- reads s']
      [("Node", s')] ->
        case lex s' of
          [(funcName, s'')] ->
            case lookupFunc funcName of
              Nothing -> []
              Just f -> [(Node f ts, s''') | (ts, s''') <- reads s'']
          _ -> []
      _ -> []
```

I've assumed `lookupFunc` with a type like
`String -> Maybe ([a] -> a)` to look up the function names.
But this type will only allow for functions like `head` that work on
any `[a]`.  You probably want to allow functions like `sum` that
will work on particular element types.  So function lookup needs to be
in a class.

```
class Funcs a where
  lookupFunc :: String -> Maybe ([a] -> a)

instance Funcs Int where
  lookupFunc "sum" = Just sum
  lookupFunc _ = Nothing
```

And add the Funcs constraint like

```
instance (Funcs a, Read a) => Read (EvalATree a a) where ...
```

---

Final note: if you do want to use parser combinators, Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
(in base) has `readS_to_P` which lets you easily use Read instances as
part of parsers.  I'm not sure if other parser libraries have an
equivalent.